# How to verify text to speech in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-text-to-speech

How do you know if text to speech is working correctly in unity? I have  speech to 
to speech streaming but don't know if its actually working as intended. trying to follow this tutorial.

https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/create-a-3d-digital-human-with-ibm-watson-assistant-and-unity3d/#r_step2

can't connect to assistant either :( no clue

Comment: Are you referring having issues with Text to Speech or Speech to Text? You mention `speech to to speech` in your question. You should be able to run the service examples scene in the examples directory of the Watson Unity SDK, make the Text to Speech GameObject active and input credentials.

Comment: speech to text is fine its the text to speech part. I'm not sure if it's actually working correctly. I think the idea is it creates an audioclip. I'm not sure where to get that or  how to do it. The service examples only occasionally work for me. I've had it create an assistant in the IBM cloud page once and then it refused to work again on exactly the same settings. if I untick assistant. and play the scene. It starts up with I'm sorry... this is text to speech and I have no idea if it's meant to do that.